Camera Setting up on Ubuntu 24 for Raspberry Pi 5
I am working on a project using Ubuntu 24 on a Raspberry Pi 5 and encountering several issues while trying to set up a camera. I would greatly appreciate assistance in resolving these problems.
Issues Encountered:
CSI Camera with libcamera: I attempted to connect a camera via the CSI port and use libcamera. After successfully cloning and trying to install the libcamera application, I was unable to proceed. Specifically, when attempting to use any libcamera command (such as libcamera-hello), I receive the error:
command not found
Despite following the available instructions, I cannot seem to get libcamera functioning on Ubuntu 24.
USB Camera (OV5640 5MP): I tried using an OV5640 5MP USB camera as an alternative, configuring it with V4L2. However, I was still unable to establish streaming with this camera. Despite my efforts, the system could not successfully stream or display video using this USB camera.
External Webcam: I also tested an external USB webcam. While I was able to load an image in the Cheese application, the streaming functionality was not working afterward. The image would load initially but failed to stream video beyond that point.
Request for Assistance:
I would greatly appreciate guidance on the following:
Correct steps to ensure the libcamera package installs and runs properly on Ubuntu 24 with a Raspberry Pi 5.
How to troubleshoot and resolve the "command not found" error for libcamera.
Steps to establish video streaming using a USB camera with V4L2.
Any suggestions for troubleshooting the streaming issue with the external USB webcam after loading an image in Cheese.
Thank you in advance for your assistance.

You have to enable the camera in the /boot/config.txt so that its declared in the dtb and the kernel module is loaded. libcamera does not contain the hello app, you also need libcamera-apps. The firmware of the raspberry has to be up to date, which it probably is
